# Code analysis ignores OpenMP constructs; analyzing single-threaded code

Tags: recursion, parallel-processing, openmp, binary-search-tree, traversal

```
void inorderTraversal(struct node* node)
{
    double start;
    double end;
    start = omp_get_wtime();
    printf(" %d Thread : %d \n", node->data,omp_get_thread_num());
    #pragma omp parallel sections 
    {
            #pragma omp section
            if (node->left)
                inorderTraversal(node->left);

            #pragma omp section 
            if (node->right)
                inorderTraversal(node->right);
    }
    end = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Calisma zamani %f sn \n", end - start);
```

/* I take this error. why ?  Analyzing single-threaded code how can I fixed ?   This is traversal function binary search tree code works, but no parallelism. I need to parallelism with openMP  */
}

Comment: This is the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61649062/traversal-binary-search-tree-with-openmp isn't it ?

Comment: its not there anymore

Comment: Still unanswered